# atof() returning float instead of double

Tags: c++, string, double, atof

I have text files containing numbers with precision upto 12 decimal places.

So to load the number into a c++ vec I wrote this

```
void txt2vec(const std::string& file, std::vector<double>& data)
{
std::string line;
std::ifstream myfile(file);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {

        std::cout << atof(line.c_str()) << std::endl;
        //data.push_back(atof(line.c_str()));
    }
    myfile.close();
}
}
```

`atof` should return a double but I am getting float

This is the output of the program

```
 -0.0340206
 -0.0873645
  0.0789533
  0.115022
  0.0809852
  0.118469
  0.113328
  0.112746
 -0.0331071
```

where as it should be

```
  -0.0340205617249
  -0.0873644948006
   0.078953281045
   0.115022487938
   0.0809852406383
   0.118468873203
   0.11332821846
   0.112745501101
  -0.0331071354449
```

Comment: `ostream::operator<<(double)` prints 6 digits of precision by default. See also `std::setprecision`

Comment: No, you're not getting a `float` result, you're getting a `double` result.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting the expected values, but you are not printing the full precision in your shown code.

The `<<` operator for output streams and doubles has a default precision of 6 for general use and readability. See [`std::ios_base::precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision).

> The default precision, as established by `std::basic_ios::init`, is 6.

If you want to display the full number you need to set the precision with the number of digits a double may contain, e.g. use `numeric_limits`.

```
std::cout << -0.0340205617249 << std::endl; // -0.0340206
std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
std::cout << -0.0340205617249 << std::endl; // -0.0340205617249
```

See also [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).